# How can I automate the filling of inputs and selecting options and general flow of a web site on development mode?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing a web app with Angular. I waste hours everyday trying to test a specific feature I'm  trying to make in a modal which appears after filling so many fields, selecting options from selects, and clicking then filling the input again in the modal.

I tried forcing first input, which is a select input (from an external library; that's why I can't use `template references` and `viewChild` methods) of the very first step I need to fill to get to the modal, but I have no luck. I tried this:

```js
  constructor() {

    setTimeout(() => {
      const selectContainer  = document.querySelector('.select_container');
      const selectInput = selectContainer!.querySelector('.w-full') as HTMLInputElement;
      console.log('about to click!')
      selectContainer.click();
    },100)
  }
```

However, click does not occur, because options are not shown.

Is there a way to do this in a better (and working) and less rudimentary way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but based on the code you provided:
Did you by any chance mean to write `selectInput.click();` instead of `selectContainer.click();`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can do this with unit tests. You pass in mock data (state/props) and test if your feature appears.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to achieve. I've tried selectInput.click() , selectContainer.click(); .. I've done DOM traversing and obtaning the real HTML Input, that this library (A library incomplete and in development) inserts in the DOM... I've tried to target the very HTMLInputElement input and force a click. But I can't get the select showing it's options as soon as the component initializes. After achieving that first goal, my thought was to do the same with all the remaining inputs, selects , buttons and so many other fields I need to fill only to check specific features?